# Unable to access certain websites from a computer

Tags: windows-xp, networking, website, connection, internet-connection

One of the desktop computers in my office is unable to access some particular websites. We've tried from Chrome, IE, Firefox, but no luck. eg:

```
 http://spsims.wto.org/ -> click on "Regular notifications"
```

On the affected computer, every browser times out after the click.

Whereas it should redirect the user to

```
 http://spsims.wto.org/web/pages/search/notification/regular/Search.aspx
```

How can I diagnose this further? This is a Windows XP machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one or more of the following:

- Scan it with a malware scanner, such as ComboFix, Malwarebytes or SuperAntiSpyware.
- Check the hosts file for dodgy entries.
- Make sure it has a proper antivirus.
- Remove all browser toolbars.
- Reset the browser settings.

And so on ...

Once you've done all of that and made sure Windows is completely up to date, try it again.

Of course it might be blocked on the router, but that's round two of your investigation.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem with xp wherein i could not access many websites using IE,Opera and Mozilla.  I tried everything including command prompt and nothing happened.  Then finally I uninstalled the network driver and again reinstalled and everything started to work fine.  If anybody is interested they can try this method also.